# Join and display data from two tables in line chart in Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, charts

I have two tables (Incomings and Expenditures) each with two properties I wish to use (IncDate, IncCost & ExpDate, ExpCost). At the moment I am creating a line chart for the incomings table that displays the date along the bottom and the cost along the side. 
Here is the sql for that:

```
 SqlDataSource5.SelectCommand = "SELECT IncDate, SUM(IncCost) FROM Incomings WHERE AspNetUsersId = '" + userId + "' GROUP BY IncDate ORDER BY CONVERT(DATETIME, IncDate, 103)";
        statsChart.Series["Series1"].BorderWidth = 3;
```

This creates a line for incomings. I am hoping to do the same with expenditures so that the two lines are compared in the same chart. Nothing has worked and I'm at a loss as to how to go about it. Cheers in advance for any help!

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: I would have to disagree